# How it works? 4 transactions in 1 block

Tags: go-ethereum, bsc, cpp-ethereum, transfer

[image]

This address withdraws tokens from different accounts as shown above.

His steps:

1. He sends BNB to the address where there are tokens to pay the token withdrawal fee. Gas price 60 gwei
2. Withdraws tokens. Gas price 3 gwei.
3. Withdraws the remaining BNB back to your account. Gas price 3 gwei.

And all these transactions are executed in 1 block, how???

When I tried to run the same algorithm, my transactions were confirmed in different blocks.

How can I repeat the experience of this wallet?

I use my own good BSC node. And I can't create a transaction for withdrawing tokens until the block in which the transaction for depositing BNB is completed.

Maybe I need to use certain configurations of the Geth node so that before the transaction for the BNB deposit is confirmed, send the transaction for the withdrawal of tokens and the withdrawal of BNB back?...

Wallet - https://bscscan.com/address/0x615c572cef85599ea88ad38e67d313cb682d3518

Thx!

Comment: It seems like they use flashbot service to execute all the transactions in a block.

Comment: @Ismael this is BNB, flashbots is not working in bnb.